# Regex to disregard partial matches across lines / matching too much

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have three lines of tab-separated values:

1. SELL 2022-06-28 12:42:27 39.42   0.29    11.43180000 0.00003582
2. BUY  2022-06-28 12:27:22 39.30   0.10    3.93000000  0.00001233
3. _____2022-06-28 12:27:22 39.30   0.19    7.46700000  0.00002342

The first two have 'SELL' or 'BUY' as first value but the third one has not, hence a Tab mark where I wrote `______`:

[image]

I would like to capture the following using Regex:

[image]

My expression `^(BUY|SELL).+?\r\n\t` does not work as it gets me this:

[image]

I do know why outputs this - adding an lazy-maker '?' obviously won't help. I don't get lookarounds to work either, if they are the right means at all. I need something like 'Match \r\n\t only or \r\n(?:^\t) at the end of each line'.

The final goal is to make the three lines look at this at the end, so I will need to replace the match with capturing groups:

[image]

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(BUY|SELL).+\R\K\t`
- Replace with: `$1\t`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(BUY|SELL)      # group 1, BUY or SELL
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\t              # a tabulation
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1
\t              # a tabulation
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex `((BUY|SELL)[^\n]+\n)\s+` and replace with `\1\2`.

Regex Match Explanation:

- `((BUY|SELL)[^\n]+\n)`: **Group 1**

  - `(BUY|SELL)`: **Group 2**

    - `BUY`: sequence of characters "*BUY*" followed by a space
    - `|`: or
    - `SELL`: sequence of characters "*SELL*" followed by a space
  - `[^\n]+`: any character other than newline
  - `\n`: newline character
- `\s+`: any space characters

Regex Replace Explanation:

- `\1`: Reference to **Group 1**
- `\2`: Reference to **Group 2**

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/i1MWMp/1). Tested on `Notepad++` in a private environment too.

**Note**: Make sure to check the "*Regular expression*" checkbox.

Regex

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It worked, but (for me) only after I had removed the spaces after BUY/SELL in your Regex string..